# The best transformation definition for EPSG:5514 in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Which transformation definition of EPSG:4326 to EPSG:5514 is the best in position accurancy in QGIS Seletect transform dialog?

[image]

Comment: it depends on the use case: mainly the location and how the data was collected. It's because you normally have spatial (physical) deviations from the datum, which defines a geographic coordinate system like wgs84 or etrs89. Then it depends on how the data was collected, measurements with gps or terrestrial methods differ in results. (e.g. GPS is always in WGS84, but data may have been transformed to another datum). That said, I'm no geodetic expert and can't give a binding explanation.

Comment: Czechia or Slovakia? Then look at the [EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org), set the type for single transformations.